# Google oauth2 signUp does NOT prompt user for basic permissions

Tags: php, google-oauth

Trying to Add a login with google feature to my PHP site. Using the PHP client library ("google/apiclient": "^2.0")

THE FLOW:
User clicks Auth URL -> goes to account chooser page -> user logins -> Now user is NOT asked to give my SITE basic permissions. Instead, is automatically redirected to my website, where the full profile of the user is accessible.

Basically user does not get a PROMPT to see which basic permissions are being accessed.

AFAIK google asks me every time a site wants to see my profile/ when using google sign in..Have a strong feeling I am doing something wrong.

btw *if* the scope Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY is requested , then there is a prompt.

The code:

```
$gClient = new Google_Client();
$gClient->setApplicationName($clientName);
$gClient->setClientId($clientId);
$gClient->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
$gClient->setRedirectUri($redirectURL);
$gClient->setIncludeGrantedScopes(false);
// $gClient->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
$gClient->addScope(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile']);

$authUrl =  filter_var($gClient->createAuthUrl(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
```

The authURL itself (values are slightly modified):

```
https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount?
client_id=CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com&
as=-98432179o&
nosignup=1&
destination=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&
approval_state=!RANDOM-STRING1tcnJnSxIfVXhhMTh0KJH90DJXIKdtUjlFUFpiSXloVQ·ADiIGyEAAAAAWUQECDfVGilus-TfaaUHFtCDC-4RANDOMSTUFF&
xsrfsig=AHgIfL8e1NAPEmE6mWrwx1JLc_VIziWT_g&
flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow
```

Is this expected behavior? Am I doing something wrong ? if so what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended behavior.

Quoting from the blogpost here: https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/updates-to-end-user-consent-for-3rd.html

"...users should have greater visibility into permissions being requested beyond the standard "email address" and "profile" consent. By clicking to select their account, a user consents to these core permissions,. The secondary consent screen will appear only if additional permissions are requested by the application. ..."

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a different account or after revoking permissions for this app. Once an app has permissions, you don't get asked for those permissions on the next log in.